# Queria guardar o nome do usuário que está na sessão e salvar no campo id_usuario no banco de dados porém está dando erro da forma que fiz

Tags: php

Arquivo login.php

```
 <?php
 $conn=mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","xerox");

 if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['senha'])){

 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $senha = $_POST['senha'];

 $get = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'");
 $num = mysqli_num_rows($get);

 if($num == 1){
 while ($percorer = mysqli_fetch_array($get)){
 $adm = $percorer['funcao'];
 $nome = $percorer['nome'];

 session_start();
 $id_usuario = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT nome FROM usuarios");
 $_SESSION['nome'] = $id_usuario;
 $SESSION['logado'] = true;

if ($adm == 0) {
    $_SESSION['coor']= $nome;
    header ("Location: dentro.php");
}

if ($adm == 1) {
    $_SESSION['prof']= $nome;
    header ("Location: dentro.php");
}

if ($adm == 2) {
    $_SESSION['rep']= $nome;
    header ("Location: dentro.php");

} 
 } 
 } else {
    echo 'O email ou senha digitados estão INCORRETOS.';
}   
 }
 ?>
```

Arquivo reqenviada.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 //include("check.php");
 $id_usuario = $_SESSION['nome'];
 $_SESSION['nome'] = $id_usuario;
 $_SESSION['logado'] = TRUE;

 ?>
 <?php


 $assunto=$_POST['assunto'];
 $tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
 $quant=$_POST['quant'];
 $dataentrega=$_POST['dataentrega'];
 $anexo=$_POST['anexo'];

$servidor='localhost';
$banco='xerox';
$usuario='root';
q$senha='';

 $conexao = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha);
 mysqli_select_db($conexao, $banco);
 $sql= mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO requisicao (id_usuario, tipo, quant, anexo, assunto, dataentrega, status, impresso) VALUES ('$id_usuario', '$tipo', '$quant', '$anexo', '$assunto', '$dataentrega', 'pendente', 'não')");

 echo ("Requisicao enviada com sucesso!")

 ?>

 <br/><br/>


 <table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Número</th>
    <th>Requerente</th>
    <th>Data do Requerimento</th>
    <th>Tipo</th>
    <th>Quantidade</th>
    <th>Anexo</th>
    <th>Assunto</th>
    <th>Data de Entrega</th>
    <th>Status</th>

    </th>


    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> 
    <?php
    echo $_POST["id"];
    ?>
    </td>
    <td> 
    <?php
    echo $_POST["$id_usuario"];
    ?>
    </td>
    <td> 
    <?php
    echo $_POST["data_req"];
    ?>
    </td>
    <td> 
    <?php
    echo $_POST["tipo"];
    ?>
    </td>
    <td> 
    <?php
    echo $_POST["quant"];
    ?>
    </td>
    <td> 
    <?php
    echo $_POST["anexo"];
    ?>
    </td>
    <td> 
    <?php
    echo $_POST["assunto"];
    ?>
    </td>
    <td> 
    <?php
    echo $_POST["dataentrega"];
    ?>
    </td>
    <td> 
    <?php
    echo $_POST["status"];  
    ?>

    </td>
</tr>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Existe o nome do usuário salvo em algum lugar?

Comment: só no banco de dados mesmo çç

Comment: Então basta selecionar os dados do banco e guardar o nome da sessão. Qual a dúvida?

Comment: está dando erro da forma que eu fiz kkkkk

Comment: Então edite a pergunta, adicione o código referente ao problema que poderemos olhar se há algo errado xD

Comment: prontinho, sorry ><

Comment: Agora ficou confuso. Antes você queria pegar o nome do banco e guardar na sessão, mas agora quer pegar o nome da sessão e guardar no banco?

Comment: esse sistema é de requisição de xerox, e assim que a requisição fosse enviada queria que fosse salvo o nome de quem fez a requisição (no caso o usuário) no banco de dados junto com os dados da requisição :c para assim que o admin fosse analisar pudesse ver quem fez a requisição

Comment: Porque você tem aquele segundo `mysqli_query` dentro do `while`? O nome do usuário ja está na variável `$nome`. A não ser que esteja usando o nome do usuário como chave primária da tabela (o que não é uma boa ideia) não de o nome da variável como `$id_usuario`, isso só deixa o código mais confuso. Identar o código também ajuda na leitura

Comment: retirei o segundo mysqli_query mas ainda não está salvando o nome do usuário no banco de dados :/